# Access system constants using ExtUtils::Constants

Tags: perl, xs

I'm trying to export C constants from a system header using ExtUtils::Constant.

As per the doc, I have in Makefile.PL:

```
ExtUtils::Constant::WriteConstants (
    NAME => 'Foo::Bar',
    NAMES => [ qw(EPOLLIN EPOLLOUT) ]
);
```

Then in Bar.xs:

```
 #include "const-c.inc"
 #include <sys/epoll.h>  // hail mary...

 MODULE = Foo::Bar    PACKAGE = Foo::Bar
 INCLUDE: const-xs.inc
```

However, when I run a test with:

```
 is(Foo::Bar::EPOLLOUT, 4);
```

I get:

```
t/bar.t Bareword "Foo::Bar::EPOLLOUT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
```

This would not be the case if EPOLLOUT existed as a constant; i.e. it's an invalid identifier.

How is this supposed to be done?  I am not at all surprised this fails to set EPOLLOUT to the correct value -- the doc also says ExtUtils::Constant "doesn't contain the routines to scan header files to extract these constants" -- but while the `.xs` code generated is over my head, I am a bit surprised that Foo::Bar::EPOLLOUT is not recognized as an identifier with an undef value, and the fact that it isn't leaves me confused as to what to try next.

I would contemplate the source of another perl module that uses ExtUtils::Constant, but the only one I can think of that exports system defines is POSIX, which is core (if anyone else knows of one please leave a comment).

*24 hours later: Now cross-posted at [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1078589)*.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to refer to the constant as a function `Foo::Bar::EPOLLOUT()`

The ExtUtils::Constant documentation says it uses AUTOLOAD. For barewords to work they need to be defined as a "real" constant.